# react native vector icons/fontawesome not showing icons in expo cli

Tags: react-native, icons, expo, react-native-vector-icons

I had build the layout using fontawsome icons in snack expo but when run the same project in expo cli the icons are not displayed.It displayed as a cross.App workes perfectly in snack but not in expo cli.I have tried googleing the probelem but the solutions are change files in gradle i dont have a gardle file this is a snack project.Is there any solution any help will be greatfull,Thanks.

`import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';`

```
  {
    Home: {
      screen: FetchNewsApp,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="home" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Explore: {
      screen: ExploreScreenApp,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Explore',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="wpexplorer" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Search: {
      screen: SearchScreenApp,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Search',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="search" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Settings: {
      screen: SettingScreenApp,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="cog" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },

    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreenApp,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="user-circle" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

Comment: post some code.

Comment: and the import statement

Comment: Add the code in the question not in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using expo managed app just use expo vector icons
[Expo vector icons](https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/)

because react native vector icons require linking which is not possible with expo managed apps.

here is an example for expo icons on snack:
[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/expo-icons)

Answer (score 0):

You also use images replace icons it works fine,

`tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
   <Image source={require('...')} style={{}}/>
    )`

Comment: i dont want to use image as it takes too much time to load.Anyway Thanks

Comment: ionicons works fine in expo projects and ios devices,but not working in android devices

Comment: actually it works fine for me.only ion and md works good with expo cli.